# iOS , RTSP Live streaming in Background more than 3 minutes

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'm trying to upload `RTSP stream` from one IP camera to `Server` . I'm using "`FFmpeg`" third-party c library for uploading.Is it possible to continue uploading in background?Currently the live streaming got disconnected after 3 minutes in background.I want to continue the live streaming with out any interruption,if the user locked his iPhone.I've enabled:

Project Target  -> Capabilities ->Background modes ->External Accessory Communications and Background Fetch.

Is it possible to continue streaming without any interruption after 3 minutes ,the user lock his iPhone?

```
let queue:dispatch_queue_t = dispatch_queue_create("streaming", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)

                    dispatch_async(queue, { () -> Void in
                        self.startStreaming()
                    })
```

_

```
func startStreaming()
{
    let taskId = UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler { () -> Void in }

    start_stream()   // This will call FFmpeg code for live streaming

    if(taskId != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid)
    {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().endBackgroundTask(taskId)
        self.clearStreamingDefaults()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No.

The only apps that are allowed to continue to run in the background are VoIP apps, but if you abuse that background mode, your app will be rejected on submission.

Why do you need the iOS device to stand between the camera and the server? Why no have the camera send directly to the server?